# Show/Hide labels of Vector Tile layers on button click

Tags: openlayers, labeling, vector-tiles

I have displayed vector tiles layers with "application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile" format in Open Layers 3.While creating vector tile I have applied only image style. I want to display labels for existing vector tile layer when user click on button.

While creating vector tile layer I am able to display labels because we will get features so I can apply text style. But in my case when user wants see labels they click on button that time labels has to display.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Define two styles: one without labels and one with labels. For initial layer display use first style, upon button click apply second style to vector layer with `setStyle` method.

Comment: For vector layer we set but vector tile layer how to set it

Comment: If you are displaying labels your style is almost certainly a function.  If your button sets a global `displayLabels` variable to true/false you could use that in the function to determine if text should be included.

Comment: I am not getting features from vector tile to add style

Comment: OpenLayers will almost certainly be using the layer style to style features, it doesn't make sense to set a style on individual features in vector tiles.

Comment: Seeing your code would help understand what does not work and what you want to achieve.